# How do I get the identity value from a SQL Server insert using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, razor, sql-server-2014

I am using a Microsoft Razor website and calling a stored procedure as:

```
db.QuerySingle("Exec dbo.InsertSurvey @city=@0, @age=@1, @sport=@2, 
  @firstsport=@3, @secondsport=@4, @thirdsport=@5, @Survey_ID=@6", 
  searchTerm, selectage, selectsport, firstsport, secondsport, thirdsport, returnval);
```

The insert works fine but I am not getting the identity value returned.

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSurvey] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @city varchar(50),
    @age varchar(50),
    @sport varchar(50),
    @firstsport varchar(50),
    @secondsport varchar(50),
    @thirdsport varchar(50),
    @Survey_ID int output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Survey]
           ([City]
           ,[Age]
           ,[Favorite_Professional_League]
           ,[First_Professional_League]
           ,[Second_Professional_League]
           ,[Third_Professional_League])
     VALUES
           (@city
           ,@age
           ,@sport
           ,@firstsport
           ,@secondsport
           ,@thirdsport)
    SET @Survey_ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

It seems like I should specify that the `@Survey_ID` parameter in my call to the stored procedure is for output, not input.

Comment: You need to look into Razor's documentation and see how to consume an output parameter. I suspect `db.QuerySingle` is *not* the best way to call a stored procedure in any case.

Comment: just add  SELECT @Survey_ID  AS id RETURN

Comment: @mohan111 That won't be enough, since the calling code does not expect a result, and does nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Database helper doesn't support output parameters. It was never designed to work with stored procedures. You can use plain ADO.NET instead OR use QueryValue method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: `doesn't support output parameters` <--- seriously? Another big win for ORMs?

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of:

```
SELECT @Survey_ID AS id RETURN
```

in the stored procedure, and:

```
var procSurvey = db.QueryValue("Exec sp...")
```

in the code. It works now. Thank you for your help.